# how to solve Object reference not set to an instance of an object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


         num = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RegNo"].ToString());
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindTextBoxvalues();
            }    
        }
```

here it will display an error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Add a break point, debug it!  and see which line throws the error.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are trying to get a property of a null value. Can you post the stacktrace so we can see on what line the error occurs?

Comment: Your code has multiple problems, from not using properties, not checking for null for query string, not checking if the data table has any records, not using proper naming for columns, not using Sql Parameters, not disposing sql connection, sqlDataAdapter.

Comment: yes i put a breakpoint and identify which part error occured.

Comment: num = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RegNo"].ToString());

Comment: Your query string is probably empty `.ToString()` throws the error

Comment: Your Request.QueryString["RegNo"] should contain only numbers. Other wise Convert.ToInt32 will return error

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check that the querystring parameter is not null. Then you need to check that the value is actually an integer before trying to convert it. For this you can use the method `Int32.TryParse`. If the value is a convertible to an int, it will do the conversion for you at the same time.

For example:

```
if (Request.QueryString["RegNo"] != null) {
  int num = 0; 
  bool parseResult = Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["RegNo"].ToString(), out num);
  if (parseResult == true) {
    //valid number, so continue
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      BindTextBoxvalues();
    }    
  }
  else {
    //do something suitable here like display an error message or throw an exception, or continue without executing this particular piece of functionality, whatever is necessary for your application
  }
else {
    //do something suitable here like display an error message or throw an exception, or continue without executing this particular piece of functionality, whatever is necessary for your application
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx for details and more examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to avoid exception.

```
var regNo = Request.QueryString["RegNo"];
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(regNo) && IsDigitsOnly(regNo.ToString().Trim()))
{
 num = Convert.ToInt32(regNo.ToString());
}

private bool IsDigitsOnly(string str)
{
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that while this will work for this situation (since the RegNo in the DB is likely to be always positive) technically this doesn't strictly validate that the string is parseable to an int, since it will disallow negative integers (e.g. "-100"). So it's not re-usable as a general validation routine for checking integers. It's also probably less efficient that using the built-in TryParse method

Comment: @Adyson `TryParse` wont prevent from null reference exception. If there is no query string value for `RegNo`, then `ToString()` on that will give null reference exception before `TryParse`

Comment: @KiranKG `regNo.ToString()` no need to call `ToString()` again as it is already a `string`

Comment: @Bharadwaj you're correct, I have amended my answer. Thanks.

Comment: it works. i changed my coding .

Comment: This can simply be replaced by a call to int.TryParse.